# Pandas: Count like a stack using rolling

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a table like this (email is simplified to just one letter here):

```
timestamp                  | email
2018-10-17 13:00:00+00:00  | m
2018-10-17 13:00:00+00:00  | m
2018-10-17 13:00:10+00:00  | 
2018-10-17 13:00:10+00:00  | v
2018-10-17 13:00:30+00:00  |  
2018-10-17 13:00:30+00:00  | c
2018-10-17 13:00:50+00:00  | p
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  |  
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | m
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | s
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | b
```

Now, I would like to make a new column, that would count the number of times that the email repeated in the last 30 seconds before the entry, for example.

```
timestamp                  | email | count | comment
2018-10-17 13:00:00+00:00  | m     |   1   |
2018-10-17 13:00:00+00:00  | m     |   2   | (there were 2 entries in the last 30s)
2018-10-17 13:00:10+00:00  |       |   1   | (empty we count as well)
2018-10-17 13:00:10+00:00  | v     |   1   |
2018-10-17 13:00:30+00:00  |       |   2   | (counting the empty like emails)
2018-10-17 13:00:30+00:00  | c     |   1   | 
2018-10-17 13:00:50+00:00  | p     |   1   |
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  |       |   2   | (in the last 30s from this ts, we have 2)
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | m     |   1   | (the first 2 m happened before the last 30s)
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | s     |   1   |
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | b     |   1   |
```

The timestamp is a dateTime object

```
timestamp          datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Also, it's the index and it's sorted.
I first tried, this command:

```
df['email'].groupby(df.email).rolling('120s').count().values
```

But it doesn't work with a string, so I converted it to a unique number, using:

```
full_df['email'].factorize()
```

But the results doesn't appear to be right:

```
timestamp                  | email | count | comment
2018-10-17 13:00:00+00:00  | m     |   1   |  
2018-10-17 13:00:00+00:00  | m     |   2   | 
2018-10-17 13:00:10+00:00  |       |   1   | 
2018-10-17 13:00:10+00:00  | v     |   2   |  (No ideia about this result)
2018-10-17 13:00:30+00:00  |       |   3   | (Appears to just keeping count)
2018-10-17 13:00:30+00:00  | c     |   1   |  (Then just go back to 1 again... )
2018-10-17 13:00:50+00:00  | p     |   2   |
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  |       |   3   | 
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | m     |   4   | 
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | s     |   1   |
2018-10-17 13:01:00+00:00  | b     |   1   |
```

Any ideia what I'm doing wrong and how can I get what I would like to get?

Many Thanks,
Joao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` after `rolling` to count the number of times the last element of the window shows up in the window like this:

```
df['count'] = df['email'].astype('category').cat.codes.rolling('30s').apply(lambda x: sum(x==x[-1]))
```